# Hydrangea Danger

Tags: hydrangea

I have 3 Hydrangeas in pots, and just noticed that (in the last few days), 2 of them have started looking really bad - and I'm not sure why or what to do.

The days have become fairly warm (I'd imagine 24-26c daytime temps).  The plants are semi-shaded.  There has not been significant rain.  **I do wonder if I have under-watered them - but the soil feels moist to the touch when I stick my finger in**.   Both plants a above the ground, so presumably drainage is adequate.

The plants appear to be suffering quite differently.   The third plant is slightly away from these (but in similar shade).  It is in a bigger pot.

HELP?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do your pots have drainage holes? If so, do you have anything in the bottom of the pots that will restrict water flow, such as gravel?

Comment: @Jurp Yrs, pots have drainage hole and they are sitting on a flat concrete base (lid of septic system).  I was surprised how light one of the pots was when I picked it up last night (after writing this post) so I sat it in a bucket of water [and then removed it] - I'll update my feedback later today once I know if Ive made that one better or worse.

Comment: I'm pleased to confirm the soaking worked and the Hydrangea in the bottom picture is looking a LOT happier (like nothing happened to it) now.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer why the first Hydrangea was yellowing (I may update ths when I work through that), but in the case of the second Hydrangea it was indeed lack of water.

When I picked up the pot I was surprised at how light it was.  I immersed it in a bucked of water for a few minutes yesterday evening, and by today it was right as rain.